# Django: Cannot insert user profile data from model into the template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django's default auth for users and I have created a separate model to extend the user profile a bit. When I try to access the user profile info its not showing up on the page. In my view, I pass the Profile objects to the view's context but it still not working.

When I try it in the shell, I get **AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'country'**
error when I do:

```
profile = Profile.get.objects.all()
country = profile.coutry
country
```

Below is my models.py:

```
from pytz import common_timezones
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


TIMEZONES = tuple(zip(common_timezones, common_timezones))


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = CountryField()
    timeZone = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TIMEZONES, default='US/Eastern')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - {1} ({2})".format(self.user.username, self.country, self.timeZone)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from user.models import Profile

@login_required()
def home(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.all()
    return render(request, "user/home.html", {'profile': profile})
```

And finally the home.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
Account Home for {{ user.username }}
{% endblock title %}

{% block content_auth %}
    <h1 class="page-header">Welcome, {{ user.username }}. </h1>

<p>Below are you preferences:</p>

<ul>
    <li>{{ profile.country }}</li>
    <li>{{ profile.timeZone }}</li>
</ul>
{% endblock content_auth %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **many records** in profile now, coz you have `get.objects.all()`. so use it in that way.

```
profiles = Profile.get.objects.all()

# for first profile's country
country1 = profiles.0.country

#for second profile entry
country2 = profiles.1.country
```

> Alternatively in html

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
    {{profile.country}}
    {{profile.timezone}}
{% endfor %}
```

> for a specific user, get the `id` of that user and then get their profile

```
id = request.user.pk
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__id=id)
```

Now in html,

```
{{profile.country}}
{{profile.timezone}}
```

Comment: what if I only wanted to display the profile data for a specific logged-in user? do I have to change my model/view?

Comment: See I have updated my answer. Have a look and tell me if it works for you or not.

Comment: If the solution worked for you. You can upvote and select my answer. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: Will do as soon as it lets me.